# Element is trying to be found before it is present

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working on a project that requires getting multiple elements matching a class name and looping over them to get the text from each element and print it to the screen the problem is that the code repeats again and gets the last question until I kill the script I took a look at the code and noticed the element I was trying to use is always clickable so I removed that code and decided to try and catch the text related to the last text which is FINISH I took a look and found the ID and built the code below, however, the problem is that it attempts to find the element before it gets to the last question a possible solution is also attached

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    Firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
    Firefox.get('ThisIsAExampleWebsite.com')
    # Not the actual website
    # Website isn't included since it's a local business
    Username = 
    Firefox.find_element_by_id('Username_Login').send_keys('Test')
    Password = 
    Firefox.find_element_by_id('Password_Login').send_keys('Test')
    # Not actual username/password
    Article = Firefox.find_element_by_id('Article').click()
    Get_Text = Firefox.find_element_by_id('Article_Text').click()
    while True:
        Article_Texts = Firefox.find_elements_by_id('All_Text')
        for Text in Article_Texts:
            print(Article_Texts.text)
        try:
            Finish = Firefox.find_element_by_id('Finish')
            print('  Done  ' )
            break
        except:
            print('  Not Done ' )
            continue
```

Edit: I have looked into replacing the while loop with a for loop using the element that is each part of the article if I use find_elements on this class name and get the size using len() code is below

```
Length_Text = len(Firefox.find_elements_by_class_name('NextText'))
for I in range(0, Length_Text):
    Article_Text = Firefox.find_elements_by_id('All_Text')
    for Text in Article_Text:
       print(Text.text)
```

The idea behind this is if I only loop the code for how much next text there are then it won't loop the last text but this code still loops it any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you don't want the text of last element with class `'NextText'`. Correct me if i'm wrong. You can do that be subtracting `len() by 1`.

```
Length_Text = len(Firefox.find_elements_by_class_name('NextText'))
for I in range(0, Length_Text-1):
    Article_Text = Firefox.find_elements_by_id('All_Text')
    for Text in Article_Text:
       print(Text.text)
```

Comment: Yes you are correct NextText is only being used to get the size for the for loop